# Creating a web page on my local machine. Links go to file:/// instead of http://

Tags: html

This code:

```
<a href=”http://google.com”>Link goes to Google.</a>
```

Produces this link:

```
file:///C:/%E2%80%9Dhttp://google.com%E2%80%9D
```

Why is it putting file:/// etc?
I'm configuring it to be http://, absolute link. I don't remember having this issue in the past.

I'm confused. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have used different character for double quote:

try replacing `”` with `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ” with " and you are good to go. It should be

```
<a href="https://google.com">Link goes to Google.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ” to " and it should work!